# call function after youtube video end

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

I have a multiple youtube videos in my page that comes dynamically on the basis of date DESC.I want to call a function after video end.I just want to perform  this action in only one video (like latest one).All the video comming from database.
here is the video code

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" id="player_video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AEolY27i7yE?list=PLBFFEFD304803D5F5" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I have assigned a id to iframe like `"player_video"`

This is my Js code.

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    switch(event.data) {
        case YT.PlayerState.ENDED:
            log('Video has ended.');
            break;
        case YT.PlayerState.PLAYING:
            log('Video is playing.');
            break;
        case YT.PlayerState.PAUSED:
            log('Video is paused.');
            break;
        case YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING:
            log('Video is buffering.');
            break;
        case YT.PlayerState.CUED:
            log('Video is cued.');
            break;
        default:
            log('Unrecognized state.');
            break;
    }
} 
     new YT.Player('player_video', {
            events: {
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
```

But its not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'?  Is is entering the onPlayerStateChange function?